# How can we alias props when using the Hooks API?

Tags: syntax, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

Previously, I was using `[@bs.as "in"]` like so.

```
[@bs.deriving abstract]
type cssTransitionProps = {
  [@bs.as "in"]
  _in: bool,
  timeout: int,
  classNames: string,
};
```

How can I do something similar here?

```
module CSSTransition = {
  [@bs.module "react-transition-group"] [@react.component]
  external make:
    (
      ~_in: bool,
      ~timeout: int,
      ~classNames: string,
      ~children: React.element
    ) =>
    React.element =
    "CSSTransition";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything bucklescript will do it for you.

If you look at the js output you'll see that `_in` get converted to `in`

```
return React.createElement(ReactTransitionGroup.CSSTransition, {
              in: match$2[0],
              timeout: 200,
              classNames: "my-node",
              children: React.createElement("div", undefined, React.createElement(CommandsArea.make, {
                        text: text,
                        setText: match[1]
                      }), React.createElement(Toolbar.make, {
                        result: match$1[0]
                      }))
            });
```